# Ford Fiesta Oil Separator

Tags: ford, fiesta

The check engine light recently came on in my 2011 Ford Fiesta. I took it to the dealer because the local mechanic said it seemed to be an issue with the catalytic converter, which is under warranty. However, at the service center, they said the issue is with the oil/water separator (part of the PCV system), which is NOT under warranty (conveniently) and that it would cost $800 to repair! Does this seem right? They say that the oil/water separator has a crack in it, which is clearly not a result of anything I did. I imagine that crack has been there for a while, but Ford refuses to accept ownership of the problem.

Comment: What code was causing the check engine light? Posting the code here may provide clues as to which place is on the right track or why they told you what they did.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ford Parts site](http://www.fordparts.com/Commerce/PartDetail.aspx?n=%2bWOHisSvlKGvgyJvQZXZ0w%3d%3d&id=401017426&m=2&search=true&year=2011&make=Ford&model=Fiesta) the part only cost about $25.00 (USD).

I am not familiar with how to change this part, but it is entirely possible the rest of the amount quoted is for labor and ancillary parts (gaskets, etc.) to complete the job.

It might be a good idea to contact the local mechanic again. Explain what the dealer found and see what they would charge to replace it.

Comment: Replacement of the part seems relatively simple in theory, according to the service manual steps are: Remove intake manifold, Remove crankcase vent oil separator hose, remove 7 bolts and crankcase vent oil separator gasket. To reinstall install new crankcase vent oil separator gasket and tighten bolts to 9Nm. Instructions for removing the intake manifold are way too complicated for a comment though.